# Python, match bigram dict with the text

Tags: python

I'm struggling with matching a sentence of 3 words with a digram dictionary of two words, which counts the frequency of the ( 1st word and 2nd word ) and (2nd word and 3rd word). What I want is how to match that the string ( AAA BBB CCC) is in the bigram and (AAA BBB) has a count and also (BBB CCC) has a count and then we take the max?

```
Counter({
('BBB', 'DDD'): 3, 
('AAA', 'BBB'): 2, 
('DDD', 'XXX'): 1, 
('DDD', 'YYY'): 1,
('YYY', 'BBB'): 1, 
('BBB', 'CCC'): 1, 
('CCC', 'AAA'): 1, 
('XXX', 'BBB'): 1})
```

Comment: plase explain how the keys in your dictionary look like, and also the type of the 3 words sequence.... are they a string or a tuple or what?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you're trying to do? I don't think there's a general way to know if `"AAA BBB CCC"` was present in a corpus given only a bigram dictionary.

Comment: if I have a sentence ( AAA BBB CCC) and dict of the bigram frequencies. I want to compare if bigram(AAA,BBB) > bigram(BBB,CCC) then the sentence is left bracketing, else it is right bracketing.

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty straight forward to query your counter for the two bigrams that make up your three-word sentence and compare them. Here's one way:

```
def find_sentence_bracketing(sentence, bigram_dict):
    left = sentence[0:2]
    right = sentence[1:3]
    if bigram_dict[left] > bigram_dict[right]:
        return "left bracketing"
    else:
        return "right bracketing"
```

You can of course do something other than returning a string, that's just to demonstrate the basic idea.

The important piece of the code is the tuple slicing that produces the `left` and `right` bigram tuples, which can then be used to index into the dictionary.

Comment: What happens if either key is not in the dictionary or if both are not?

Comment: @Kenosis: A `Counter` instance (from the `collections` module) will always return zero for keys that don't exist, so if the dictionary is like the one in the question, there will be no problem.